# script to swap case in python

Tags: python

this script is supposed to swap case in words but the result is really weird and doesn't make sense

```
def swap_case(s):
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i].islower():
        s= s.replace(s[i],s[i].upper())
    elif s[i].isupper():
        s= s.replace(s[i],s[i].lower())
    else:
        pass
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7CAF.png)

Comment: What is some output that is abnormal in your opinion so we can troubleshoot effectively?

Comment: give sample strings, are they all uppercase or lowercase, or mixed upper and lower case words?

Comment: `replace` replaces all occurences of a char in the string, so it will change the ones you already changed or would have changed later... You should build a list of your changed chars, and `join` them at the end.

Comment: I added an exapmle result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all consider using inbuild swapcase function
Otherwise, you can use join function

E.g.

```
s = "hELLO wORLD"
# inbuilt
print(s.swapcase())
# join
print(''.join([ss.lower() if ss.isupper() else ss.upper() for ss in s]))
```

which gives you

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

You're going through each letter in the string, then replacing all instances of that letter. That means that if there's an even amount of a letter, the case won't be changed.

Also, a method, swapcase, already exists for this.

```
>>> 'Hello World!'.swapcase()
'hELLO wORLD!'
```

Comment: I was thinking of this... but reading *this script is supposed to change lower case **words** into upper case and vice versa* (emphasis mine) - I'm not sure it's correct - the description and the actual attempted code are somewhat contradictory...

Comment: @JonClements I doubt they'd be iterating through each letter in the word and trying to replace if that were the case. I guess we'll see what they say though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem-->

```
def swap_case(s):
    k=''
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i].islower():
            k+=s[i].upper()
        elif s[i].isupper():
            k+=s[i].lower()
        else:
            pass
    print(k)
```

Comment: It is more efficient to build a list and `join` it at the end

Comment: it works but it should be like this to work perfectly . thanks :)

Comment: def swap_case(s):
    k=''
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i].islower():
            k+=s[i].upper()
        elif s[i].isupper():
            k+=s[i].lower()
        else:
            k+=s[i]
    print(k)
swap_case("Hello World")

Comment: Yes. I just thought i would return him the function which is a bit less complicated and he would understand it easily. Your suggestion is very good !

Answer (score 0):

### Solution with Python

Case Swapping can be achieve using a python built-in function called `swapcase` if you want to do this manually then here is the code.

```
result = ''
    for element in (s):
        if element.isupper():
            result += element.lower()
        else:
            result += element.upper()  
        print(result)
```