# How to handle with spaces with string looping?

Tags: python, string, loops, replace

for my assignment at hackerrank, ı need to write a program that takes a string as input and returns that string in back ordering and reversed characters, that means a input like "hELLO wORLD" should return as "Hello World", ı did all the stuff but when ı try to run it, it stops on spaces, don't know how to solve.

```
def reverse(sentence):
mylist = []
splitted = sentence.split(" ")
for i in range(len(splitted)):
    mylist.append(splitted[-1])
    splitted.pop(-1)
    
for i in mylist:
    chars = []
    for char in i:
        if char.islower():
            char = char.upper()
            chars.append(char)
        elif char.isupper():
            char = char.lower()
            chars.append(char)
        else:
            char = char
            chars.append(char)
    print(chars)
    newmessage = ""
    for i in chars:
        newmessage += str(i)
    print(newmessage)
```

reverse("helLoWorld")

Comment: See [swap case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61507142/script-to-swap-case-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check [swap case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61507142/script-to-swap-case-in-python) as **Chris Charley** commented but if you want to use your code, you can skip split the **sentence** to preserve blank spaces.

```
def reverse(sentence):
    # mylist = []
    # splitted = sentence.split(" ")
    # for i in range(len(splitted)):
    #     mylist.append(splitted[-1])
    #     splitted.pop(-1)

    chars = []
    for i in sentence:
        for char in i:
            if char.islower():
                char = char.upper()
                chars.append(char)
            elif char.isupper():
                char = char.lower()
                chars.append(char)
            else:
                char = char
                chars.append(char)
        # print(chars)
    newmessage = ""
    for i in chars:
        newmessage += str(i)
    print(newmessage)


reverse('hELLO wORLD')
```

**output:**

```
Hello World
```

Comment: thanks but, ı have  to rewrite string with back ordering like if input is "hello world" it should prompt "world hello". thats why ı am using split.

Comment: well, you can use split after getting  **newmessage** to change the order of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse(sentence):
complete_string =""
mylist = []
splitted = sentence.split(" ")
for i in range(len(splitted)):
    mylist.append(splitted[-1])
    splitted.pop(-1)

print(mylist)
    
for x,i in enumerate(mylist):
    chars = []
    for char in i:
        if char.islower():
            char = char.upper()
            chars.append(char)
        elif char.isupper():
            char = char.lower()
            chars.append(char)
        else:
            char = char
            chars.append(char)
    print(chars)
    newmessage = ""
    for i in chars:
        newmessage += str(i)
    print(newmessage)
    if len(mylist)-x != 1:
        complete_string += newmessage + " "
    else:
        complete_string += newmessage
print(complete_string)
```

reverse("hELLO wORLD")