# Trying to swap case of every character in string using list comprehension and enumerate

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to take a string, check every single character in the string, and swap the case for the opposite. For example, `'Seoul'` would become `'sEOUL'`. (I realize that Python's builtin `str.swapcase` method exists, but am trying to reimplement it as a learning exercise.)

This is my code.

```
str = "My name is Shah, and I recently went to Mission Nightclub"
str_arr = [str.upper[0] + str.upper[1:] if str[index].islower() else str[index].lower for (index, val) in enumerate(str.split)]
print(str_arr)
```

The idea is that I use `enumerate` and a list comprehension. First, it takes the whole string and splits it into a list where each element is a word. Then, it'll use `enumerate` to get the index of each element in the list. Then I have two conditions: one checks if the `i`th character is lowercase, and if it is, it'll convert it to uppercase; else it'll convert to lowercase. Then, for each `i`th element in the new list created, it'll take the first element and uppercase it and the rest of the element using string slicing to get the rest of the characters in the word.

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shah/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    str_arr = [str.upper[0] + str.upper[1:]if str[index].islower() else str[index].lower for (index, val) in enumerate(str.split)]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Why doesn't my code work, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried breaking this down into smaller problems and checking that each part does what you think it does? For instance, have you tried just seeing what `str.upper[0]` is? (Also, it's not a good practice to "shadow" existing keywords and builtins, so `str` is not a good choice for a variable name.)

Comment: You. need to use `str.upper()`, not`str.upper`. It's a function. Likewise for `str.lower() `.

Comment: One Python rule of thumb: if you can't figure out why your list comprehension isn't working, write it as a for loop first. It's easier to debug, particularly by printing intermediate values as you create them in each iteration.

Comment: @CrazyChucky given ther amount of work i put in and did my best to explain everything can you please how to fix it and what i am doing wrong

Comment: @Shah The error message should tell you why it doesn't work: `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable`. If you're not sure why that's happening, take CrazyChucky's advice: rewrite the comp as a for-loop and break it down step-by step. There are multiple problems with your code, so do them one at a time. We're not just going to debug everything for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [script to swap case in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61507142/script-to-swap-case-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Python provides a built-in method for doing this:

```
>>> a = 'Seoul'
>>> print(a.swapcase())
sEOUL
```

Comment: The question has changed an invalidated this answer